# ssh login verification in perl

Tags: perl, bash, ssh

I am running following lines of code in perl script to find a df output of remote machines. this works fine and gather a info in  @df_ret untill until ssh key is uptodate. if public is corrupted or changed, its not showing any sign of error in script. if i run manually then i will be asked for the password.

```
@df_ret = split /\n/, `ssh -q $server 'df -hP'`;
```

Is there any way i can verify that if ssh login is successful then this perl script line should be executed else not. been finding many searches on it but could not reach to the ONE. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got one solution working as below;
    #!/usr/local/bin/perl

```
my $line  = `ssh $server -o 'BatchMode=yes' -o 'ConnectionAttempts=1' true`;
my $error = `echo $?`;

print "Error = $error";

if($error == 0 )
{
    print "This is good";
    @df_ret = split /\n/, `ssh -q $server 'df -hP'`;
}
else
{
    print "This is bad";
}
```

Comment: Fix: `my $error = $? >> 8;` because `$?` is an internal variable of Perl (that has the same name as the `$?` of your Unix shell).

Answer (score 0):

Check the result of the `ssh` exec before splitting it:

```
$text = `ssh -q $server 'df -hP'` or die "unable to ssh\n";
@df_ret = split /\n/, $text;
```

Comment: Here is the output of the first line..../1.pl
Password:
Password:
Password:
./1.pl: line 1: =: command not found

Comment: I am having something like "ssh server -o 'BatchMode=yes' -o 'ConnectionAttempts=1' true" which seems to be working till mimited extend...searching for good sols